# Jump to certain line in IDLE?

Tags: python, python-idle

I use IDLE when I'm coding in Python and really enjoy it's simplicity.  One thing I don't like though is when you need to navigate to a certain line and have to scroll around the place, haphazardly guessing how far you have to go to reach it.  So, my question is **is there a way to jump to a certain line number in IDLE for Windows?**

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html

Comment: @MayurKoshti can't believe I didn't see this!  Thanks so much

Comment: You can use `ALT+G` to go on specific line. The line number is displaying at right-bottom of the IDLE.

Answer (score 3):

**Kudos to @MayurKoshti**

As explained in the [IDLE Documents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html), if you go *Edit* -> *Go to Line*, a box appears in which you can enter a line number to jump to.  The shortcut for this is **Alt + G**

Answer (score 0):

Edit then go to line :D
or Alt + G